# Hide div when user reaches the bottom of page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to hide a div element when user scrolls and reaches the bottom of the page and display it again when the user scrolls back up. For example consider the following navigation bar which is named "nav".

HTML

```
<div class="nav"></div>
```

CSS

```
.nav{
 width:100%;
 height:50px;
 position:fixed;
 }
```

I want to hide the `nav` div element when scroll reaches bottom of the webpage. How can I make this possible. Can I use CSS for this or should I use JavaScipt instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div id="nav"></div>
```

**JS**

```
document.onscroll = function() {
        if (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY > document.body.clientHeight) {
            document.getElementById('nav').style.display='none';
        }
    }
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k77fdzyu/1/

Comment: I am glad it helped you. Happy coding.

Comment: Is there any way to display again when the user starts scrolling back to top.

Comment: @RonaldPMathews yes, just add another if statement to that function

Comment: This worked for me too. I just added an "else" statement for displaying it back.

Answer (score 5):

If you want the element to re-appear, include an else statement with `display='block';`:

```
document.onscroll = function() {
    if (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY > document.body.clientHeight) {
        document.getElementById('nav').style.display='none';
    }else{
        document.getElementById('nav').style.display='block';
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this easily with jQuery as follows:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
   if (jQuery('body').height() <= (jQuery(window).height() + jQuery(window).scrollTop())) {
    jQuery('.nav').hide();
   }else{
    jQuery('.nav').show();
   }
  });
 });
```